# Struct y Clases ( Y preguntas generales)

Tags: c++

He leído en varias paginas de Google lo que he preguntado pero no logro entender exactamente lo siguiente(si alguien me puede decir con palabras mas simples y con ejemplos se lo agradecería):

1. ¿Puedo tener una struct dentro de una clase y vice versa?
2. En cuanto a los códigos (escribir) es mas llevadero struct que clases? por ejemplo imaginamos que tengo Struct Persona con su nombre y apellido:

   Para el main (struct) para guardar un dato hay que poner: 
   cin.getline(Persona.nombre, 20 (ejemplo del char de nombre), / 'n`);

   En cambio en las clases en el main hay que volver a crear la variable string nombre y al guardar seria así: cin>>nombre
3. Hay dos tipos de constructores: el constructor vacío es decir no inicializado Complejo(): r(0), y(0).
   Y el constructor inicializado Complejo( int _r , int _y) : r{_r}, y{_y}.
   ¿Por qué uno se inicializa y el otro no?
   ¿Cuando es mejor utilizar uno que otro?

Gracias

Comment: El formato del sitio es **una pregunta por publicación**; además, han de ser preguntas **concretas**, no *opinables*. Tu pregunta, en el estado actual, es muy posible que termine cerrada. Siempre puedes pulsar en [edit] para mejorarla las veces que sean necesarias. Un saludo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Evita hacer muchas preguntas dentro de la misma.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Puedo tener una struct dentro de una clase y vice versa?

Claro:

```
class CExterna
{
    struct SInterna {};
};

struct SExterna
{
    class CInterna {};
};
```

Los ejemplos anteriores son `struct` dentro de clases y vice versa. Pero son **tipos** de datos, por lo que puedes declarar variables de ese tipo:

```
SExterna se;
SExterna::Cinterna ci;
CExterna ce;
CExterna::Sinterna si; // Error! SInterna es privada.
```

Supongo que en realidad te referías a **instancias**:

```
class Clase{};
struct Estructura{};

class CEjemplo
{
    Estructura e;
};

struct SEjemplo
{
    Clase c;
};
```

Los ejemplos anteriores son **instancias** de `struct` dentro de clases y vice versa. Pero son tipos de datos, al declarar variables de ese tipo, puedes acceder a los datos internos:

```
CEjemplo c;
SEjemplo s;

std::cout << &c.e << &s.c;
//              ~ <--- Error, 'e' es privado!
```

> En cuanto a los códigos (escribir) es mas llevadero struct que clases?

Es indiferente. La única diferencia es la visibilidad de los datos:

- Las `struct` tienen todos sus miembros públicos por defecto:

  ```
  struct S
  {
      int publico; // Por defecto, es público.
  private:
      int privado; // Debimos poner la etiqueta 'private' para hacerlo privado.
  };
  ```
- Las `class` tienen todos sus miembros privados por defecto:

  ```
  class C
  {
      int privado; // Por defecto, es privado.
  public:
      int publico; // Debimos poner la etiqueta 'public' para hacerlo público.
  };
  ```

> Hay dos tipos de constructores

No. Hay 4 tipos:

- Constructor por defecto, no recibe parámetros:

  ```
  struct S
  {
      S(); // Constructor por defecto.
  };
  ```
- Constructor de copia, recibe un elemento del mismo tipo:

  ```
  struct S
  {
      S(const S&); // Constructor de copia.
  };
  ```
- Constructor de movimiento, recibe un valor temporal del mismo tipo:

  ```
  struct S
  {
      S(S&&); // Constructor de movimiento.
  };
  ```
- Constructor con parámetros, recibe los parámetros que se consideren necesarios:

  ```
  struct S
  {
      S( ... ); // Constructor con lo que sea...
  };
  ```

> ¿Cuando es mejor utilizar uno que otro?

- Usa el constructor por defecto, cuando tu objeto necesite hacer operaciones al ser construido.
- Usa el constructor de copia, cuando tu objeto necesite hacer operaciones al ser copiado.
- Usa el constructor de movimiento, cuando tu objeto necesite hacer operaciones al ser movido.
- Usa el constructor con parámetros, cuando quieras personalizar la construcción de tu objeto.

---

No voy a entrar en más detalles de cada cosa, te animo a hacer preguntas específicas de las dudas que te puedan haber surgido en este hilo. (una duda por pregunta, por favor).